# Detect if JavaFX Media required codecs are installed

Tags: java, javafx, media, codec

According to the following:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/certconfig-2095354.html

In order for JavaFX media to work, the given OS needs proper codecs installed.

In my application, I am trying to play an mp4 video. If the given platform is *not* able to play it, I display a static image instead.
In such a case, if it is unable to play it, I was expecting it to throw an exception and I would handle it accordingly.
However, it does not do so and instead displays a blank area where the video should be.
How can one detect if the required codec is installed or not?

I was testing this on Windows Server 2008 where I got this symptom. Windows 7, 8, and 10 work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to check if the OS has the codec because Java includes most of them (Mpeg-4/mp4 is included), the problem is that window's server edition isn't able to play videos.

Comment: From the link (for Win 7 and 8): "The pre-installed Microsoft AAC and H.264 DirectShow decoder filters are used by default." and "If none of these decoders is available, AAC and H.264 decoding will fail."
My basic issue is that if these decoders are not available, it doesn't throw an exception.

Comment: JavaFX uses the popular open source framework GStreamer which includes many codecs, some examples: MP3, WAV, ACC, AIFF, PCM, MPEG-4 (including H.264/AVC and AAC) and FLV (VP6 and MP3).

Comment: The reality is that when running on Windows Server it *doesn't work* and it *doesn't throw an exception* telling me that so I can handle it.

Comment: At your situation, I would just test for windows server, because every other system either wouldn't be able to run the program, or works with JFX correctly

Comment: I am now detecting if it is running on Windows Server but I consider that a workaround solution. It would be better if it would simply throw an exception or let me call some method to check. BTW, it does run JavaFX correctly, just not the media.